# Could not install a project with npm i or npm i --force

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-install, node-sass, npm-package

I am trying to install a react js project on my computer but could not do so, these are the errors i am having after writing npm I or npm i --force in my console.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please copy the console text to your question instead of posting a screenshot